# Scrolling web page using selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping this webpage for usernames which loads the users after scrolling

Url to page : "http://www.quora.com/Kevin-Rose/followers"

I know the number of users on the page (in this case no. is 43812)
How can I scroll the page till all the users are loaded? 
I have searched for the same on the internet and everywhere I got almost same line of code for doing it which is:

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, )")

How can I determine the vertical position to ensure that all the users are loaded? Is there any other option to achieve the same thing without actually scrolling?

```
   from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import urllib

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.quora.com/')
time.sleep(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

form = driver.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
time.sleep(10)
#add explicit wait

username = form.find_element_by_name('email')
time.sleep(10)
#add explicit wait

username.send_keys('abc@gmail.com')
time.sleep(30)
#add explicit wait

password = form.find_element_by_name('password')
time.sleep(30)
#add explicit wait

password.send_keys('def')
#add explicit wait

password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(30)

#search = driver.find_element_by_name('search_input')
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@name='search_form']//input[@name='search_input']")))

search.clear()
search.send_keys('Kevin Rose')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Kevin Rose")))
link.click()
#Wait till the element is loaded (Asynchronusly loaded webpage)

handle = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(handle[1])
#switch to new window 

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Followers")))
element.click()
```

Comment: There are certainly options. Please show the complete code you have now (including scrolling part). Thanks.

Comment: I dont think its of any use but I have added the code. This is just code to log into the site and navigate to particular page. I dont know what to add in y coordinate position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is nothing special appearing after the last followers bucket is loaded, I would rely on the fact that you know how many followers does the user have and you know how many are loaded on each scroll down (I've inspected - it is 18 per scroll). Hence, you can calculate how many times do you need to scroll the page down.

Here's the implementation (I've used a different user with only 53 followers to demonstrate the solution):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

followers_per_page = 18

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # webdriver.Firefox() in your case
driver.get("http://www.quora.com/Andrew-Delikat/followers")

# get the followers count
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@class, "FollowersNavItem")]//span[@class="profile_count"]')))
followers_count = int(element.text.replace(',', ''))
print followers_count

# scroll down the page iteratively with a delay
for _ in xrange(0, followers_count/followers_per_page + 1):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10000);")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Also, you may need to increase this `10000` Y coordinate value based on the loop variable in case there is a big number of followers.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Right now I am trying the following script which appears to work perfectly    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: ^Nope. Code which I mentioned above didnt load all the users.

Comment: @Siddhesh thank you for the another interesting challenge. Sorry, I didn't quite get - does it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks again for putting so much efforts.