# How can I parse long web pages with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been using following code to parse web page in the link https://www.blogforacure.com/members.php. The code is expected to return the links of all the members of the given page.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib
    r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.blogforacure.com/members.php').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
    headers = soup.find_all('h3')
    print(len(headers))
    for header in headers:
       a = header.find('a')
       print(a.attrs['href'])
```

But I get only the first 10 links from the above page. Even while printing the prettify option I see only the first 10 links.

Comment: results are loaded through ajax calls. When you reach the page end, new results are fetched from server.

Comment: How can I deal with that?

Comment: My apporach is to use Selenium to interface with the page and scroll to the bottom, as described in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870906/scrolling-web-page-using-selenium-python-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are dynamically loaded by making AJAX requests to the `https://www.blogforacure.com/site/ajax/scrollergetentries.php` endpoint.

Simulate them in your code with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) maintaining a web-scraping session:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.blogforacure.com/site/ajax/scrollergetentries.php"
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
    session.get("https://www.blogforacure.com/members.php")

    page = 0
    members = []
    while True:
        # get page
        response = session.post(url, data={
            "p": str(page),
            "id": "#scrollbox1"
        })
        html = response.json()['html']

        # parse html
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        page_members = [member.get_text() for member in soup.select(".memberentry h3 a")]
        print(page, page_members)
        members.extend(page_members)

        page += 1
```

It prints the current page number and the list of members per page accumulating member names into a `members` list. Not posting what it prints since it contains names.

Note that I've intentionally left the loop endless, please figure out the exit condition. May be when `response.json()` throws an error.

Comment: I a new to this and I have a very basis question as on how did you get know about site/ajax/scrollergetentries.php ? How to get that for another page. and can you explain to me session.post()

Comment: @athira I've used browser developer tools, network tab when the page was loaded, then scrolled and saw multiple requests to the `scrollergetentries.php` endpoint. Hope that helps.